# Induced representation, isomorphism between vectorspaces

Tags: representation-theory

I want to prove the following statement:

**The mapping $Ind_H^G{V}\rightarrow V^m: \psi\mapsto(\psi(g_1),\ldots,\psi(g_m))$ is a isomorphism.**

Here is $g_1,\ldots,g_m$ a representing system of $G/H$ with $G$ a group and $H<G$. $Ind_H^G{V}$ is given by:

$$Ind_H^G{V}=\left\{f:G\rightarrow V: f(hg)=\rho(h)f(g)\ \forall g\in G\ \forall h\in h\right\}$$

I can prove the this is a linear map but how to prove injectivity and that the mapping is surjectiv? Can someone say me why we can use such a representing system of $G/H$? Thank you for help.

Comment: What is $\rho$?

Comment: $\rho$ is a representation of $G$ on $V$.

Comment: Do you know a basis for $Ind^G_H V$? Can you show that the mapping sends this basis to a basis of $V^m$?

Comment: Is the basis given by $f(x_i)$ with $(x_i)$ a representing systeem of $G/H$?

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that by definition, the underlying vector space of ${\rm Ind}_H^GV$ consists of functions that are determined completely by their values on a set of coset representatives $g_1,\ldots, g_m$ of $H\backslash G$, because once you know what your function does to a coset representative $g$, the condition $f(hg) = \rho(h)f(g)$ means that you know what it does to the entire coset. This will give you injectivity. Surjectivity is just rephrasing that to concoct a vector in ${\rm Ind}_H^GV$, you can choose its values on coset representatives of different cosets independently of each other.